# Data extraction from confluence page

Tags: python, web-scraping, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I want to extract few information from a confluence page.
Data is stored in table format inside the confluence.

Is there any way to get this done?
Im using python for this scrape.

Comment: "Is there any way to get this done?" - Yes, probably. What is your specific problem?

Comment: information are stored in a key value pair inside the table.
i want to get the values one by one and store into an output file.

Comment: Well, there is no problem. I am looking for a way to get the data efficiently, like using any confluence native option that i am unaware of.

Comment: okay. Let's forget the confluence api.
I want to pick the values of the variables(for example Name as variable inside one column and its value 'Logan' inside the another column) which are given in a table format. Apologies, if the provided information failed to bried the context.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently ... you can connect directly to the Confluence backend database; see

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-datasource-connection-937166084.html
- https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4c/8.1.0/integrations/connect-to-databases

However:

- I am not aware of any public documentation of the Confluence SQL schemas.
- You can probably infer the schemas from the Confluence Hibernate (ORM) data model; see https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-data-model-127369837.html , but you will need to understand how Hibernate mappings work.
- I am not aware of any documentation or examples in Python.  (Try Googling ...).
- My recommendation would be to learn Java + Hibernate, or hire a Java dev to do this project for you.
- I *expect* this would only work for a self-hosted Confluence installation.  In the web-hosted case, you should be using the APIs.
- Using the Confluence APIs *should be simpler* than database access.  The APIs should be your preferred approach, unless you have *real* performance requirements<sup>1</sup> that can only be met by direct database access.

---

<sup>1 - I am talking about real pragmatic requirements ... not just "I want it to be as efficient as possible 'cos I hate writing inefficient code" or "The boss / client said make it as fast as possible.".</sup>

Comment: If someone knows that it is possible to get database access in a Confluence instance hosted by Atlassian, please comment ...